# Is it possible to scaffold out an entire UI in Qt using the Model/View/Delegate design pattern?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm reading up on the latest version of Qt, and it seems the Model/View/(Delegate) pattern is what's being pushed. It should be conceivable then to completely wire up the views without writing a single model, at least for the purpose of specing out how it looks. Is this the advised approach?

Also, where are the event wirings supposed to be placed? I assume that signals are coordinated by the MainWindow code?

Answer (score 0):

You will need dummy models of course, made using existing Qt model classes. Looking at empty views is somewhat unhelpful, since you can't check out the primary delegates for the underlying model. Without any data, about the only delegates you can check out are the ones used in the headers, IIRC.

There are no event "wirings" on the view side of things, except for providing programmatic means of interacting with the view. The models may need a lot of interaction, depending on what's being modeled

Conceptually, you may have just one model that represents the data in your application, but it'd be a lot of spaghetti to expose various aspects of that model to the specialized views. You may then use view-models as adapters: they'd take the big model and expose a targeted slice of it, making it easier to consume by views. That's the pattern widely used in .net WPF.